# Use of Cuda Thrust device_vector crashes

Tags: c++, cuda, runtime-error, gpu, thrust

Below I've posted some code that I'm using to try and get a feel for the CUDA thrust library. Before anyone says anything I know this is an extremely inefficient way to find prime numbers, I just want something to test parallelism. Unfortunatly when I run this I get an error here is what pops up:
`Unhandled exception at at 0x76FCC41F in Thrust_2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: thrust::system::system_error at memory location 0x0022F500.`

If I switch the `device_vector` to a `host_vector` in the doTest function I no longer get the error and the program works flawlessly. Why does this happen and how can I get it to use the device_vector without crashing? I would like to do as much in parallel is possible.
Also the entire program works as intended with a host_vector.

PS:

I'm using VS2012

Cuda: V5.5

GPU: geforce gt 540M

Thrust: Got with cuda.

Thanks in advance!

```
  struct prime{
__host__ __device__
    void operator()(long& x){
    bool result = true;
    long stop = ceil(sqrt((float)x));
    if(x%2!=0){
        for(int i = 3;i<stop;i+=2){
            if(x%i==0){
                result = false;
                break;
            };
        }
    }else{
        result = false;
    }
    if(!result)
        x = -1;
 }
};
void doTest(long gen){
  using namespace thrust;
  device_vector<long> tNum(gen);
  sequence(tNum.begin(),tNum.end()); // fails here when using a device_vector
}
int main(){
   doTest(1000);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `doTest` function makes no use of your `prime()` functor.  Is that your intent?  Are you suggesting that your `doTest` function will fail as written? Or is the failure occurring in some other part of the code (perhaps that uses the `prime()` functor)?

Comment: voting to close.  SO expects: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. "  You haven't provided a SSCCE.org code.

Comment: The prime() does work as intended it is working, the device_vector is what causes it to crash

Comment: I edited the code to make it a little more clear whats going on

Comment: Could you give us some more information? GPU used, CUDA version, Thrust version (if not using the one given with CUDA) etc.

Comment: Try catching the `thrust::system_error` exception and print out its `.what()` to see what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was i had the wrong compiler arguments, I feel really stupid now...

i was compiling for 1.0, I switched it to 2.0 and now its working.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem:

```
void operator()(long& x){
bool result = true;
long stop = ceil(sqrt(x));
```

And in fact you should be receiving a warning message from the compiler about it.

The `sqrt` function available in device code is only available for `float` and `double` arguments.  Your argument is of type `long`.  This means the compiler will attempt to use a host-library version of the `sqrt` function, which will not work in device code.  When you create your vector as a host vector, this is not a problem, as the functor is being run in host code.  However when you switch to a device vector, the functor (running on the device) will crash at that point, and throw a thrust error.

As a simple test, you could modify it to:

```
long stop = ceil(sqrt((float)x));
```

and see if it eliminates the crash. Whether or not the cast from `long` to `float` is valid for your code is something you will have to decide.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't eliminate the problem. The crash still happens only when i use a device_vector

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't expect it to eliminate the problem.  Your code doesn't make use of the functor (that I can see.) Therefore the functor could not be the issue.  But if you ever do use the functor, you will want to fix that.